# Не работает MetroMessageBox

Tags: c#

У MetroMessageBox нет метода Show. MetroFrameWork установлен и подключен. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой подскажите как решить.

Comment: А вы прописали `using MetroFramework;`? Вот [видео](https://youtu.be/r2D0AmZfE2Y?t=31) на эту тему.

Comment: Вот [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzVNRsssG5I) где все показано еще лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Установите пакет [MetroModernUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroModernUI/) (автор Dennis Magno) вместо пакета MetroFramework. 
Также не забудьте удалить все ссылки MetroFramework и зависимые от него пакеты:

- MetroFramework.RunTime
- MetroFramework.Design
- MetroFramework.Fonts